# ConvLSTM2D data preparation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use ConvLSTM2D for 1700 of 90x3 data in keras.

I already did CONV2D which data is (1700x90x30x1). Data format is (batch, rows, cols, channels)
Now I want to use CONVLSTM2D but I found out I should change the data format to (samples, time, rows, cols, channels).

> samples=1700  , row=90 , cols=30,  channels=1

How to determine the "time"?

Answer (score 1):

ConvLSTM2D, or LSTM as a special type of recurrent neural network in general, are used when the input data is a time series. This enables to take advantage of temporal properties within the data.
In case of ConvLSTM2D, the input is usually a video, consisting of multiple frames. Consequently, you have to reshape the data the following way:

```
samples=1700 , time=t, row=90 , cols=30, channels=1
```

where *t* is the number of frames in the video.

As an example, let's say we want to do video classification (or frame prediction) based on a short video clip of 10 frames, then *t=10*.
This of course only makes sense in case the image frames you are having are in a temporal order. Simply use *tf.reshape(...)*.

Comment: Thanks for replay, my data is1.1M of  3-axis sensor with 20Hz sample time.
I used window of 90x3.

Comment: I have 1700 of this 90x3 frames which each frames is associate to 1 class